# How can I use the rand feature in a font?

Tags: fonts, truetype-fonts, opentype

I want to use the feature specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/typography/opentype/spec/features_pt#tag-rand) in a similar way like the `kern`, `liga` or any other feature.

I am completely new to fonts but currently using FontForge to import `.fea` into my font. Does this have the capability or do I have to rely on another method?

Comment: This isn't a programming or script writing service. What research have you done, and what have you tried?

Comment: Should I have asked the question on StackOverFlow? And research... I did a lot. But I couldnt find any Implementation at all using the rand feature. The only thing I found is using "loops" in some sort of way. You do that by looking at the context and if the same kind of alternative class already appeared, I switch to a different one, then again and again until I run out of alternate classes and use the first one. But I am really not a fan of this and I would rather use rand(if I understand it's bahaviour correctly) for more pseudo randomness. I dont understand Microsofts or Wikis expl of rand

Comment: You need to tell us the research you've done so that we know what not to suggest, among other things. You need to show us the things you have tried. You need to explain what you have read that you don't understand and what about it you do not understand.

Comment: https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/4045 seems to indicate that its not supported, but the closure there's for being old, not a wontfix or a fixed issue. https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting.html and https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting-alpha.html seem to indicate its scriptable, I don't know enough about fontforge or font work to actually post an answer but it feels like a good starting point to refine a question from.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding `rand` add irregularity in the letters/glyphs.

From other site kern pairs and ligatures are strictly defined in to the font. So by by definition they have totally different roles.

Comment: and how could one achieve the latter?